# Modal desactivado dentro de un iframe

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

estoy trabajando con un iframe y dentro de este estoy abriendo un modal, pero sucede que al abrirlo, el modal se bloquea totalmente, hace el efecto de ponerse gris tal y como hace un modal pero se pone gris todo el contenido dentro del iframe, incluyendo el modal, he estado intentando hacer un `window.parent.$("#Modal").modal()` pero no funciona, abre igualmente el modal dentro del iframe. Ayuda !!

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<iframe id="formularioTr"  name="formularioTr" height="470px" width="100%" style="border:hidden;">$divpropiedades .= <input id="'.$nombremetadato["idDocumentoPropiedad"].'" '.$eventoblur.'  name="'.$nombremetadato["idDocumentoPropiedad"].'" class="form-control '.$clase.'" type="text" placeholder="Seleccione '.str_replace('_', ' ', $nombremetadato["tituloDocumentoPropiedad"]).'" onblur="abrirModal('.$idLista.',this.value);"> $divpropiedades .= <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div style="" class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Selecci&oacute;n de Dependencias</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ACÁ VIENE EL CONTENIDO DEL MODAL
  </div>
</div>
```

El onblur ejecuta una funcion java script 
`function abrirModal(idLista,value)
{
window.parent.$("#ListaSelect").modal()
}`

Comment: Coloca el codigo que tienes hasta ahora para poder reproducir el problema y ayudarte de mejor manera.

Answer (score 1):

Eso ocurre porque el `z-index` del `modal` ha cambiado quizá por un elemento padre de donde se encuentra el `modal`, para resolver esto hay que aumentar el numero de `z-index`, por defecto trae `1050` y el `backdrop`(parte obscura) trae `1040`.

Muchas veces por cuestiones de diseño o para identificar ciertos modales estos pueden ir dentro de un elemento padre el cual tiene una regla que aplica para todos sus hijos que deben tener `z-index` de `1000`.

Para evitar eso puedes crear tu una regla para el `modal` o bien para el `backdrop` en tu CSS.

```
.modal-backdrop {
    /*En caso de que quieras modificar el backdrop*/
    z-index: 1040 !important;
}

.modal {
    /*En caso de que quieras modificar el modal*/
    z-index: 1050 !important;
}
```

> **NOTA:**
>
> Use los mismos números por defecto que trae el bootstrap pero estos pueden variar dependiendo del `z-index` del padre.
>
> 1. En caso del `div` con clase `modal` puede incrementarse el `z-index` hasta llegar al frente.
> 2. En el caso del `div` con clase `backdrop` puede ser menor al `div` con clase `modal`.
>
> Se agrego el `!important` para indicar que el modal debe aplicar ese `z-index` y debe tomarse en cuenta sin importar el que le indico un elemento padre